# How do I display image files as links?

Tags: images, media, library, linking

I'm a WP newbie and need some help.

I have about 5000 images to upload to my site and need to link each one with a specific entry in a list. The thought of going through 5000 entries (it's a plant species database) and linking each one individually to an image fills me with dread, so I was wondering if there is a way of (or plugin for) displaying an image as linked text?

Basically I want to batch highlight a number of images in my media library and insert them onto a page as names/text (oak tree, elm tree etc...) that link to their corresponding media file.

I hope this all makes sense! Any help for this non-coding newbie will be much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such "non-coding newbie"-bulk-thing for the process. You have to do that for each of the image, when you are uploading the image to the site and/or post/page.
[image: image linked to external URL]

On the right panel of the media upload pane, change "Link To" to "Custom URL" and put the URL (whatever you like - internal or external) into the next text field.

Then whether or not you insert multiple images into the post/page, it'll link to the link given here.